# TouchJSON, dealing with NSNull

Tags: objective-c, null, touchjson

Hi
I am using TouchJSON to deserialize some JSON. I have been using it in the past and on those occasions I dealt with occurrences of NSNull manually. I would think the author had to deal with this as well, so me doing that again would just be overhead. I then found this in the documentation:

> Avoiding NSNull values in output.

```
NSData *theJSONData = /* some JSON data */
CJSONDeserializer *theDeserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
theDeserializer.nullObject = NULL;
NSError *theError = nil;
id theObject = [theDeserializer deserialize:theJSONData error:&theError];}
```

The way I understand it the user of the class can pass a C-style null pointer to the deserializer and when it encounters a NSNull it will insert the values (NULL) passed to it. So later on when I use the values I won't get NSNull, but NULL.

This seems strange, the return value is an NSDictionary which can only contain Objects, shouldn't the value default to 'nil' instead?

**If it is NULL can I check the values like this?**

```
if([jsonDataDict objectForKey:someKey] == NULL)
```

It would seem more logically to be able to do this:

```
if(![jsonDataDict objectForKey:someKey])
```

No to mention all the cases where passing nil is allowed but passing NULL causes a crash.

**Or can I just pass 'nil' to the deserializer?**

Much of this stems from me still struggling with nil, NULL, [NSNULL null], maybe I am failing to see the potential caveats in using nil.

Comment: I commented below, but for the sake of posterity on this question, NSDictionary *cannot* contain nil as a key OR a value. From the Cocoa docs: "Neither a key nor a value can be nil; if you need to represent a null value in a dictionary, you should use NSNull."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`nil` and `NULL` are actually both equal to zero, so they are, in practice, interchangeable.  But you're right, for consistency, the documentation for TouchJSON should have used `theDeserializer.nullObject = nil` instead of `NULL`.

Now, when you do that, your second predicate actually works fine:

```
if (![jsonDataDict objectForKey:someKey])
```

because TouchJSON omits the key from the dictionary when you have `nullObject` set to `nil` (or `NULL`).  When the key doesn't exist in the dictionary, NSDictionary returns nil, which is zero so your if condition works as you expect.

If you don't specify `nullObject` as `nil`, you can instead check for null like so:

```
if ([jsonDataDict objectForKey:someKey] == [NSNull null])
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers it perfectly, as long as I can consistently expect a nil value to be returned I'll be fine.

Answer (score 48):

For another JSON library, but with the same issues, I've created the following category on NSDictionary:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (Utility)

// in case of [NSNull null] values a nil is returned ...
- (id)objectForKeyNotNull:(id)key {
   id object = [self objectForKey:key];
   if (object == [NSNull null])
      return nil;

   return object;
}

@end
```

Whenever I deal with JSON data from said library, I retrieve values like this:

```
NSString *someString = [jsonDictionary objectForKeyNotNull:@"SomeString"];
```

This way the code in my projects become a lot cleaner and at the same time I don't have to think about dealing with [NSNull null] values and the like.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang. I can see the need for that category if your JSON library of choice does not offer the "nullObject". It is a mess dealing with NSNull every time you have to access your +15 properties Model Entity:)

Comment: This is a good way to do it (and in fact how I do it in my own apps). The advantage of this is that you can still check if a key exists in a dictionary with a null value; with TouchJSON's `nullObject` set to nil, you can't distinguish between a null value and a missing key.

Comment: Key value coding will translate between NSNull and nil in collections for you. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-178726

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries which deal with it. One of them is [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) in **Swift**, another one is [NSTEasyJSON](https://github.com/bernikowich/NSTEasyJSON) in **Objective-C**.
With this library (NSTEasyJSON) it will be easy to deal with such problems. In your case you can just check values you need:

```
NSTEasyJSON *JSON = [NSTEasyJSON withData:JSONData];
NSString *someValue = JSON[someKey].string;
```

This value will be `NSString` or `nil` and you should not check it for NSNull, NULL yourself.