# How to check value is coming from json is null or not?

Tags: iphone, json, uilabel

I want to check result of json is null or not ..I used this code

```
- (NSString *)likesCount {
    if ([facebook valueForKey:@"likes"] == [NSNull null]) {

        return @"";
    }
    else {

    return [facebook valueForKey:@"likes"];

    }
}
```

`likes = 1`; if it exists and if it is null `"like"` is not visible in output.. But if it is not present then it is returning `(null)` .. I used above code but it is not working.

I am printing this value of likes in UItableviewcell

```
UILabel *commentLike = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 70, 100, 20)];
commentLike.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0];

NSString *commentLikeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[(Facebook *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]likesCount]];
    commentLike.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Person"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:commentLike];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this category on NSDictionary, code will be much cleaner:

[TouchJSON, dealing with NSNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716942/touchjson-dealing-with-nsnull/5719428#5719428)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (NSString *)likesCount {
    if ([[facebook valueForKey:@"likes"] isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || [facebook valueForKey:@"likes"] == nil) {

        return @"";
    }
    else {

    return [facebook valueForKey:@"likes"];

    }
}
```