# objective-c json-framework: How to parse dates, nulls, and everything else in between efficiently?

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data, json-framework

Scenario:
Ruby on Rails app that returns JSON to an iOS application using json-framework to parse the JSON and push the data onto Core Data objects.

Problem:
Many of attributes returned from in the JSON can be null and a large number of them are not simple strings (e.g., they are DateTimes with timezones, integers, floats, etc...).

Question:
What is the most efficient way to handle such JSON?  Does json-framework (or something else perhaps) have any helpers to make parsing such data easier ... -or- ... do I simply gotta do [NSNull null] checks on each and every attribute and if not null do the appropriate conversion to NSDate, NSNumber or whatever?

Thanks -wg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to handling Null values, I suggest making use of a category on NSDictionary:

[TouchJSON, dealing with NSNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716942/touchjson-dealing-with-nsnull/5719428#5719428)

Comment: +1 You can pass messages to `nil` and the code will continue to work (it just doesn't do anything).

Comment: I kinda like this one too that I created for Core Data:

- (NSNumber *) numberAsBoolForKey:(id)key 
{
    // check for null
    return [self objectForKeyNotNull:key] == nil ? 
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] : 
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:[[self objectForKey:key] boolValue]]; 
}