# reading 'NULL' on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, null, nsjsonserialization

so I've used JSON serialization and been using

```
NSString *referencestr = [[notificationarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Reference"];
```

and it's getting data fine and displaying it on a table view. However, when the data is a NULL, my table crashes and my app shuts down. how should I solve this problem or read the NULL as nil.

Comment: Have you tried checking for NSNull?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TouchJSON, dealing with NSNull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716942/touchjson-dealing-with-nsnull)

Comment: Clarify what you mean by `NULL`. What do you really have?

Comment: U can check with responsetoselector call on Ur result of to make sure it support the specific call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your `notificationarray` was created with a call to `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:encoding:]`.  That call will happily give you an array that contains instances of `NSNull` if there are `null` objects in the JSON being parsed.

Your client code should be robust against an uncooperative data provider.  You should check the class of your `[notificationarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`.  If you're hoping for the object to be an `NSDictionary` then you could check like this:

```
id theObject = [notificationarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // Work under the assumption that theObject is a dictionary.
} else {
    // Log an error, bail out, etc.  Whatever's the appropriate
    // response for malformed data.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario,you can check the value whether the value is null or not.And for that make one to check it.

```
  if ([[notificationarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Reference"]!=[NSNull null]) {
       lblDescription.text=[[notificationarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Reference"];
   }
  else
   {
     //any value you wants to display in label
   }
```